# Using puppeteers to get iframe when given the iframe id

Tags: node.js, iframe, ember.js, puppeteer

So, I've got a bit of code in the Chrome Dev Tools like this:

```
<div class="ember-view" id="ember123">
    <iframe src="http://yaddayaddayadda" id="sso-frame" class="sso-iframe">
    .
    .
    other elements I will loop around and get
    .
    .
    </iframe>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the iframe using Puppeteerjs.  I can't use id="ember123" since ember id's dynamic.  Is there some way to get the element handle via the  id?

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
const frameHandle = await page.$('iframe[id="sso-iframe"]');
const frame = await frameHandle.contentFrame();

await frame.type('[data-some-selector="true"]', 'some text');
```